# Joomla admin won't open: "Unable to load dynamic library..."

Tags: php, web-services, joomla

I have uploaded my Joomla site in live server. When I open its backend, it asks for a username and password.

After login, it opens a blank white page but the front site is working fine. It also works in my local server.

When I see the error log in the `SITE_ROOT/administrator/error_log` file, it displays these errors:

> [04-Jun-2015 11:59:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/soap.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.
>   [04-Jun-2015 11:59:14 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.

Comment: Do these files exist? What are their permissions? /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/soap.so, /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

Comment: Go to your joomla configuretion file located at the root  named as `configuration.php` and edit the `error_reporting` as `maximum` and check what errors you are getting.

Comment: i am set error reporting maximum but not display any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable this extensions in php.ini if that possibility exists.
Or if you have ssh access - log in via terminal and install this extensions 
(yum install php-soap).
If your server doesn't support this - maybe you should change hosting provider.

Comment: I have not access of shell access so if any other way for it so please give me.

Comment: Ask your host to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when you have old code running on a newer version of PHP. If you are on the current version of Joomla (really anything recent) it is not coming from the core, it is coming from an extension, probably a plugin.  Yes, look at error reporting but also you can disable plugins you have added one at a time until your find the one causing the problem.

Comment: i have set error reporting maximum also but its not display any error on page.

Comment: Joomla version is 3.4.1 and i have not install any other extensions like plugins etc. i have just install custom component.